# replacing failed hard disk in raid 1 on dell emc cx300

Tags: hardware, storage-area-network, dell, raid1, emc

how can I replace failed disk in slot 12 in raid 1 on san dell emc cx300

I HAD Configured the san with hot spare hard disk in slot 13.  Is it enough to remove it from it's slot an put instead of it  a new hard disk and then it  automatically rebuilt  the array with out losing the data and what hot spare hard disk do . is it take the place of the failed disk and what happened to it when i put new disk instead of the failed disk

is there any risk when replacing failed disk in raid 1 like as losing the data or copy data from new hard disk to the second disk in raid 1 array instead of rebuilding the new disk in the array with the data exist in the second disk

Answer (score 2):

The hot disk in slot 13 should now be active drive in the array.  The drive in slot 12 that failed should be replaced with the same drive that failed.  Once the drive is replaced in slot 12 the array will sync the new drive.  Slot 13 should turn back into a hot spare once the sync is complete. Depending on the drive size it can take several hours to sync.